# Changing a single state setting in D3D11

Tags: render, direct3d11

It would seem that D3D11's api is a bit clunky, or I'm not using it right.

Is it true that this is the minimum set of steps to change a single rasterizer state in D3D11 (I'm using change to wireframe mode rendering as an example)

```
  // variables to hold the current rasterizer state and its description
  ID3D11RasterizerState * rState ;
  D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rDesc ;

  // cd3d is the ID3D11DeviceContext  
  cd3d->RSGetState( &rState ) ; // retrieve the current state
  rState->GetDesc( &rDesc ) ;    // get the desc of the state
  rDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_WIREFRAME ; // change the ONE setting

  // create a whole new rasterizer state
  // d3d is the ID3D11Device
  d3d->CreateRasterizerState( &rDesc, &rState ) ;

  cd3d->RSSetState( rState );    // set the new rasterizer state
```

Seems a lot longer than 9's

```
  cd3d->SetRenderState( D3DRS_FILLMODE, D3DFILL_WIREFRAME ) ;
```

Comment: don't forget to release your rState instance after calling RSSetState to avoid a memory leak.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or you could keep the state desc 'global' to your code or class, then simply change the fillmode and set with RSSetState ( with the original state with new change)? Instead of retrieving and setting.

Comment: Yes. The more I use D3D11, the more I realize _they want you to manage state very carefully_. Its basically forcing you to use [state blocks which were available in d3d9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206121(VS.85).aspx), but I never used them